# AWS EC2 instance cannot see another instance on a specific port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created two EC2 instances using CloudFormation - one for the Apache web-server, another one for the PostgreSQL DB. For some reason the web-server cannot telnet into the DB instance on port 5432 even though the DB instance can telnet into the web-server instance on port 80. When I check the DB instance from localhost, it is working fine and telnetting to the localhost 5432 successfully. There are two security groups for each instance:

```
 "TheWebServerSecurityGroup" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Security Group for The web-server instance",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" }
      ],
      "VpcId" : { "Ref": "TheVPC" },
      "Tags" :  [ { "Key": "Name", "Value":  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup" } ]
    }
  },
  "TheDBSecurityGroup" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Security Group for The DB instance",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "5432", "ToPort" : "5432", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" }
      ],
      "VpcId" : { "Ref": "TheVPC" },
      "Tags" :  [ { "Key": "Name", "Value":  "TheDBSecurityGroup" } ]
    }
  },
```

What might be wrong with the configuration? Any help is appreciated.

UPD: I tried adding the following inbound/outbound rules, but with that it becomes impossible to install packages via yum:

```
"TheOutboundRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
      "Properties":{
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": 0,
          "ToPort": 5432,
          "DestinationSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheDBSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          },
          "GroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          }
      }
  },
  "TheInboundRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": 0,
          "ToPort": 5432,
          "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheWebServerSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          },
          "GroupId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "TheDBSecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId"
              ]
          }
      }
  },
```

I also tried adding just the inbound rule (without an outbound one), but it does not work either.

Comment: What is the reason of using a VPC when you allow all traffic inbound? Can you try and source the web servers SG to the DB security group, check the 
 docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html not sure this will solve your issue but might, basically what this does is saying whatever resource is attached to web servers SG will be allowed to connect to resources attached to the DB SG. (for the rule you do not need to specify port 5432 though it's a good practice otherwise chose ALL meaning "-1")

Comment: After I add inbound and outbound rules, it becomes impossible to install the packages via yum :( please check my updated configuration, maybe you can suggest something

Comment: Security groups are stateful. So all outbound traffic is allowed in. So your yum command should be fine with egress roles.

Comment: But for you main question, is your ec2 and db instance in the same VPC and subnets? Is where any private subnet in your setup? And do you have any egress role on you ec2 to allow it to telenet to your db instance?